# Dependent, Non-Contiguous, Dynamic Named Range in Data Validation

Tags: excel, dependent-type, contiguous

In Excel 2010, I have a formula that works like this:

```
=OFFSET(OFFSET(Table!$E$8,0,0,1,1),MATCH(Criteria1!$C9&Criteria2!$D9,Plan[Wirecentre]&Plan[Type],0)-1,0,COUNTIFS(Table[Criteria1Range],Criteria1!$C9,Table[Criteria2Range],Criteria2!$D9))
```

Let's assume Criteria 1 is "A". This works great if the Criteria 1's range looks like this:

- A
- A
- A
- B (won't be included in list, as it does not match Criteria 1

If the list looks like this:

- A
- A
- B
- A

Then the dropdown list that produces the output of the formula is polluted, and in fact includes B.

What am I missing in my syntax?

Comment: Any reason all of this logic has to be crammed into a named range?  You could just add a couple columns to roll up the rows where critera=A and point your named range to that.

Comment: Because then I would need many, many columns. The only way to mitigate this is to keep it dynamic.